# How to flash a large binary file to the 512-Mbit Quad-SPI memory of the STM32F7308-DK board?

Tags: stm32, flash, linux, stm32cubemx

I have a STM32F7308-DK board:

[image]

I want to upload my custom binary `code.bin` for the board to execute it and display output on the screen.

For that, I downloaded and installed the [STM32CubeProgrammer](https://www.st.com/en/development-tools/stm32cubeprog.html) software.

Firstly, I check that the software finds the connected board:

```
sudo ./STM32_Programmer.sh --connect port=swd

# prints:
Connect mode: Normal
Reset mode  : Software reset
Device ID   : 0x452
Device name : STM32F72x/STM32F73x
Flash size  : 64 KBytes
Device type : MCU
Device CPU  : Cortex-M7
```

Then I try to upload the binary code to the board as follows:

```
sudo ./STM32_Programmer.sh -c port=swd --write code.bin 0x08000000
```

to get an error:

```
Memory Programming ...
Opening and parsing file: code.bin
  File          : code.bin
  Size          : 230868 Bytes
  Address       : 0x08000000 

Erasing memory corresponding to segment 0:
Error: Operation exceeds memory limits
```

**How to upload the binary file to another location (e.g. 512-Mbit Quad-SPI) containing enough memory and load it from that location?**

Comment: did you read the error message?

Answer (score 2):

The microcontroller on that board only has 64kB of flash. You're trying to upload ~230kB. Your .bin file is too large, as the error message says.

Comment: yes, but maybe I can upload the code to another location (e.g. `512-Mbit Quad-SPI Flash memory`) and load it from there?

Comment: Looked at the ref manual. You cannot boot from the external flash memory. So, the real question is: why is the image so large? Are you compiling graphics assets in to your firmware? If so, you'll need to take them out of the firmware, add code to access the QSPI memory, add code to find images in teh flash memory and then load them as needed.

Comment: The other thing you can do is keep the firmware as is, and develop a new smaller firmware that sets up the QSPI flash memory, and then begins executing the "real" firmware from there. Looks like ST has an application note for that: AN5188

Comment: So I have a file 'loader.bin' which will execute "real" firmware from QSPI flash memory. How to install my 'code.bin' into QSPI memory?

Comment: The STM32CubeProgrammer manual has instructions on page 24.

Comment: You should probably make your own loader.bin file that can load the larger file directly into the external flash.